# is there an R code for converting from wide to long when you have more than 1 unique id in R?

Tags: r, long-integer, widechar

I have the following data that i want to convert from wide to long.

```
id_1<-c(1,2,2,2)
s02.0<-c(1,1,4,7)
s02.1<-c(2,2,5,8)
s02.2<-c(NA,3,6,NA)
id_2<-c(1,1,2,3)
df1<-data.frame(id_1,s02.0,s02.1,s02.2,id_2)
```

I would wish to have the following output based on two unique ids, and added new variable say n, that defines the position of 's02' in each row

```
id_1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
id_2<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
s02<-c(1,2,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,NA)
n<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
df2<-data.frame(id_1,id_2,s02,n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('s02'), values_to = 's02') %>%    
  group_by(id_1, id_2) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number())
```

Comment: hello @akrun kindly look at  my edited code and assist.

Comment: @SamMwenda sure, i am checking

Comment: Dear @akrun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209019/is-there-an-r-code-for-the-following-data-wrangling-and-transformation could you assist in my updated question here please?